Skipping simplification in linear equation yields quadratic equation
When learning about linear equations, I can't help but notice that the equation $\frac{x}{x}=x$ can be be turned into $x=x^2$ if I do not simplify $\frac{x}{x}$ to 1:
$$\frac{x}{x}=x$$
$$x*\frac{x}{x}=x*x$$
$$x=x^2$$
Notice that I multiplied both sides by $x$ on step 2, and yields $x=x^2$ on step 3.
However, $x=\{0,1\}$ for $x=x^2$ and $x=1$ for $\frac{x}{x}=x$.
Now comes the wierd part, the prooving process of $0^)=1$ is based on
$$\frac{0^0}{0^0}=0^{0-0}=0^0$$
$$x=0^0$$
$$\frac{x}{x}=1$$
$$0^0=1$$
But if $\frac{x}{x} = \{0,1\}$, it means that:
$$\frac{0^0}{0^0}=0^{0-0}=0^0$$
$$x=0^0$$
$$\frac{x}{x}=1$$
$$0^0=\{0,1\}$$
Something must be wrong. Is it ONLY because I skipped the simplification process or is there something else?

The equation $x/x = x$ is equivalent to $x = x^2$ with $x \neq 0$. They also both have the single solution $x = 1$. Simply multiply both sides in the first equation with $x$ to see this. It is however important to notice that when stating that $x/x = x$, it is implied that $x$ cannot be $0$, since then the left hand side is not well defined.
Also, keep in mind that $0^0$ is not well defined. If you try using this expression, you should not be surprised to find weird things.
